# Unit-testing a controller that uses $http

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, jasmine

I have a simple controller and the first thing I need it to do is assign a value to scope.

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.listForms = 'some list';
}
```

The following test for the controller works as expected:

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {

    var ctrl, scope, httpMock;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        ctrl = $injector.get('$controller');
        ctrl(TestCtrl, { $scope: scope });
    }));

    it("assigns to scope", function() {
      expect(scope.listForms).toMatch("some list");
    });
});
```

But when I change the function to get the list from my API

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/listForms').success(function(list) {
    $scope.aListOfForms = 'some list';
  });
}
```

and the test changes to

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {

    var ctrl, scope, httpMock;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        httpMock = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        httpMock.when('GET', '/tactical/api/listOrderForms').respond("an order form");

        ctrl = $injector.get('$controller');
        ctrl(TestCtrl, {
            $scope: scope,
            $http: httpMock
        });
    }));

    it("gets the list from the api and assigns it to scope", function() {
      httpMock.expectGET('tactical/api/listOrderForms');
      expect(scope.orderFormList).toMatch("an order form");
      httpMock.flush();
    });
});
```

I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
Expected undefined to match 'an order form'.
Error: No pending request to flush !
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$http uses `$httpBackend` to talk to external resources. You have mocked `$httpBackend`, but the controller still needs to talk to it trough `$http`s interface.

This should do it:

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {

    var ctrl, scope, httpMock;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
        httpMock = $httpBackend;

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        httpMock.when('GET', '/tactical/api/listOrderForms').respond("an order form");

        ctrl = $controller;
        ctrl(TestCtrl, {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it("gets the list from the api and assigns it to scope", function() {
      httpMock.expectGET('tactical/api/listOrderForms');
      httpMock.flush();
      expect(scope.orderFormList).toMatch("an order form");
    });
});
```

Comment: But nowhere have you modified the actual implementation of $httpBackend. So how does Angular know to not call (whatever) methods are on the real $httpBackend object but instead call the httpMock when $http.get() is called? I am terribly confused here (new to Angular)

Comment: Nikhil, $http will ask for $httpBackend when $http is initialized. $httpBackend is a singleton (there exists only one instance) and httpMock is a reference to it. Registering callbacks and doing stuff on this $httpBackend instance that is shared between the test and $http is what makes this work.

Comment: I have looked at dozens of examples and explanations and no where has this been made clear.  Now things make a little more sense.

Answer (score 3):

you can't replace $http service as $httpBackend service for your controller manually.

Change

```
    ctrl(TestCtrl, {
        $scope: scope,
        $http: httpMock
    });
```

to

```
    ctrl(TestCtrl, {
        $scope: scope
    });
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call httpMock.flush() before the expect().  The flush call simulates the response returning from the "back end," calling the success function that was bound to the http request.

Comment: I did not realise the reason that the flush() had to go first, so I have learnt something, tired it both ways and I still get the same Errors.